# Enabling keyboard shortcuts on iPad for app that supports iOS 12 and 13

Tags: ios, swift, mac-catalyst

I have an iOS app that supports iOS 10 up-to iOS 13 and recently added Catalyst support to it. Through an extension to AppDelegate keyboard short-cuts are supported, and I would like to enable them on iPad as well.

```
extension AppDelegate {
  override func buildMenu(with builder: UIMenuBuilder) {
    super.buildMenu(with: builder)
    guard builder.system == .main else { return }

    // Add menus and shortcuts
  }
}
```

This compiles fine on the Catalyst target, but when building for iOS the following error is given: *'UIMenuBuilder' is only available in iOS 13.0 or newer*

The obvious solution is put an availability check in:

```
@available(iOS 13.0, *)
extension AppDelegate {
  override func buildMenu(with builder: UIMenuBuilder) {
    super.buildMenu(with: builder)
    guard builder.system == .main else { return }

    // Add menus and shortcuts
  }
}
```

but then the error changes to *Overriding 'buildMenu' must be as available as declaration it overrides*.

So for now I excluded the extension from the build on iOS to get a working build, but that means no short-cuts on iPad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same exact issue as you. Use:

```
#if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
```

around your extension instead of the `@available` suggestion by Xcode.

Comment: That doesn't help: yes the app will compile for iPadOS but the keyboard shortcuts don't work there because that code is excluded.

Comment: For iPadOS keyboard shortcuts, I use: override var keyCommands:, not buildMenu.

Comment: Thanks, by overriding keyCommands I can get it to work.

Comment: A more extensive description can be found on https://nshipster.com/uikeycommand/